# While creating REST API, How authentication token should be used

Tags: web-services, api, rest

While creating REST API, what is the best practice to use authentication token.
API should except the authentication token in url itself or in HTTP-HEADER.
What is the best place for the authentication token and why?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to check out one of the common authentication protocols and probably use an existing stable implementation of it.
OAuth2 is the obvious choice - http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: I do agree with you. But there we must have do it by this way. So we don't have choice.

Comment: In any case, sending the token as a parameter in the URL is less secure since there's a good chance it will be logged somewhere along the way (on the web server, proxy server etc.).